# In GDB, is there a way to tell if a SIGSEGV was was due to too much memory being allocated?

Tags: linux, memory, gdb, out-of-memory

I am trying to debug a mysterious SIGSEGV based on a core file.  Usually when the root cause is a bad memory access, I see the signal handler somewhere in the stack trace and it's fairly trivial to find the piece of code that triggered the segmentation fault.  This time I do not see any signal handler called, and all the call stacks are pointing to relativity innocuous pieces of code or waiting for events.

I strongly suspect, due to some recent changes, the root cause is some sort of 'out of memory' issue during runtime.  None of the call stacks are pointing to an obvious allocation culprit.  There is also no useful message in dmesg or syslog.

Is there any way to definitely tell that the root cause was some sort of out-of-memory issue, and if so, exactly what allocation was responsable?

Comment: Linux? Because linux generally fails to handle out of memory correctly. It overcommits and kills random processes to compensate. Specifically, `malloc` does not fail by returning a null pointer, but it can fail by not returning at all. (If Linux killed you)

Comment: @MSalters Yes, specifically RHEL 7.3 which uses the 3.10.0 kernel.

Comment: You've double checked that a SIGSEGV handler is installed?

Comment: @aschepler I am not sure how I would check that posthumously, but the signal handling code hasn't changed in more than a year, and this would be the first seg fault that it hasn't caught.

Comment: Sounds like heap corruption to me